# Is there any way by which I can trigger a function at firebase (by firebase itself)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any way by which I can trigger a function at firebase (by firebase itself) that is I want to update firebase database by firebase server itself.

I am developing a **Car Rental application** in which user rent a car (say for 2 days).
In that case, the car will be booked for 2 days and it will be shown as **BOOKED** in the application. 
So, what I want is when these 2 days are over then firebase automatically change the status of the car from **BOOKED** to **AVAILABLE** in the real-time database.

Comment: You should use [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) for that.

Comment: Yes, you are right...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Http Cloud Functions which you can trigger by a cron job. (e.g. at midnight). But for the cron job you will need to use an external tool.

Another option would be to compute the status of the car each with the help of a set date (e.g. current date + 2 days).

Sadly firebase hasn't the functionality to store a property as computed value (yet).

You can check out the blog post about it: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html